# Word for something that happened to oneself due to circumstances

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe one's action of being swayed/led by the circumstances around themselves?

Example :

> A girl establishes a house only after inheriting a large sum of money. She just built it because her circumstances favored her.

Trying to find a word for a person who just does something because of circumstances and not because of their ethics.

Comment: Not sure, but how about **carried away** because of the circumstances?

Comment: good but looking more for a single word

Comment: May be **influenced**? I think swayed conveys what you want you say! Why are you looking for a different word?

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE! I advise taking the site [tour] to get a feel for how the site works. The goal of this site is to provide detailed answers to questions about English. Because of this, questions are expected to provide detail and context to make it easier for other users to write good answers.

Comment: For example, you can [edit] your question to list some words you considered, together with a note to say why they weren't adequate for what you were trying to express.

Comment: @Lawrence hope this helps.

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan please look at the edit , maybe this explains better ?

Comment: @Yasha Yes, that helps. Are you talking about the girl doing things on a *whim*? That is, she just 'felt like doing it' and so she built the house because she could, once she got the inheritance? Or are you saying that it was 'expected' of her to build a house once the inheritance money came in, so she gave in to the people telling her to build, instead of making up her own mind about what she wanted to do with the money?

Comment: You can use the phrase "good fortune" to refer to lucky circumstances for a person. It would be a good fit for your example. "She only built it because of her good fortune."

Comment: @Lawrence whim is the word for now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that the girl in your example came into a huge sum of money and bought a house simply because she felt like doing so and was able to afford it (*cf* "because of circumstances"), rather than because it was a considered decision (*cf* "because of their ethics"), then you can say she did it *on a whim*.

> **Whim** *noun*
>   1 A sudden desire or change of mind, especially one that is unusual or unexplained: she bought it on a whim:
>   *Apparently on a whim, Wonka suddenly decides to reopen his doors to five children.*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whim)